# Запись в файл, который используется в другом процессе

Tags: c#, winforms, dropbox

Проблема такова: я создаю файл в папке dropbox, он сразу начинает обрабатываться и появляется ситуация, что файл используется процессом dropbox. Есть ли возможность добавлять данные вот в этот файл пока dropbox его обрабатывает? Речь идёт именно про добавление новых данных, а не изменение старых. Асинхронные методы не работают, выдавая эксепшн, что файл сейчас использется другим процессом.

Comment: Либо при создании файла его не отпускайте, пока нужен. Либо ждите, когда дропбокс файл отпустит, потом в него пишите.

Comment: Делаете фоновую задачу, в которой периодически проверяете доступность файла на запись пока Dropbox не освободит файл, затем пишите в него данные.